# how to call the constructor of the inner class node in Static main Function

Tags: java

```
package practice;
class LinkedList
{
    Node head;  // head of list

    /* Node Class */
    class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;

        // Constructor to create a new node
        Node(int d) {data = d; next = null; }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkedList lkd=new LinkedList().new Node();
    }
}
```

Comment: `LinkedList.Node lkd = new LinkedList().new Node(1);`...?

Comment: You should make that a static class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your constructor is taking one and only one parameter. Unless you override with a constructor that takes no parameters, try:

```
LinkedList.Node lkd = new LinkedList().new Node(**int d here**);
```